# getting the frequecy/count of a range of numbers in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

In the housing file, there is the median income column with values ranging from `0.499` to `15.001`. I need to a code to get the number of houses that have a median income value between 2 and 5.

Anyways, I just tried this. It works, but I think there are cleaner ways

```
def mid_class(i):
    if 2<i<5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
sum(housing['median_income'].apply(lambda y: mid_class(y)))
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: li=[]
for x in housing['median_income']:
    if 2<x<5:
        li.append(x)
len(li)    THIS WORKED THOUGH, I FEEL THERE'D BE A CLEANER WAY TO DO IT

Answer (score 0):

After your comment I'd say the clean way is very subjective.

You can have a very pythonic/professional looking line of code. But if it's not readable/understandable or more complicated then it should be without any other advantage (better in speed or space usage) it's shıouldn't be considered:

Now to your question:

### Returning a boolean

Most of the time people check a condition then they return `True` or `False` values. This step is unnecessary. In your example:

```
def mid_class(i):
    if 2<i<5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The line `2<i<5` already returning a boolean. Then you check the boolean with an if statement to return a boolean. TL;DR just return the value of `2<i<5`.

```
def mid_class(i):
    return 2<i<5
```

### Calling a function within a `lambda` function

`lambda` functions are anonymous functions. Which mean they're functions. So you do not need a function to be called inside a `lambda` function. Just use the `lambda`:

```
sum(housing['median_income'].apply(lambda y: mid_class(y)))
```

can be changed to

```
sum(housing['median_income'].apply(lambda y: 2<y<5))
```

So the code you've written can be shorted to the line above. Never forget there will always be other ways achieve the same thing. The best one is the one you understand and can explain.